# Can someone explain this condensation pattern?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, condensation

What are the mechanics behind the formation of these patterns? Why do they bear visual semblance to results from the Cahn–Hilliard theory of phase separation?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Related - [The guy who figured out how snowflakes work](https://www.veritasium.com/videos/2021/12/2/the-guy-who-figured-out-how-snowflakes-work)

Comment: Tangentially, hello from Building 8!